# Graph Coloring Visualization

Tags: java, visualization, genetic-algorithm, graph-coloring

I've written an genetic algorithm that tries to find the chromatic number for a given graph. I've been using the [DIMACS benchmark graphs](http://www.info.univ-angers.fr/pub/porumbel/graphs/) to test it.

I have to present the results of my algorithm to my faculty at end of the term, but the graphs are not visually interesting. Are there any good libraries out there (in Java hopefully since that is what our GA is in) for dynamically coloring images? I've been looking around and all I've found are GIS stuff (I'm thinking I just don't know what to call this sort of library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

- JUNG http://jung.sourceforge.net/
- JGraphT and JGraph library http://jgrapht.org/visualizations.html

Both of them can handle million of nodes/edges (if you have enough RAM). As I remember, they also allowing coloring of nodes / edges.